# svelte-select : How to show option from APi onPage load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, svelte

In svelte-select, I want to show the option as selected coming from the backend, I can see options in the dropdown and can select them, but I wanted to show the option that is already in the backend on the initial page load and also on refresh the options which I selected gets cleared. Any props from the library that could help or any example?

Comment: Hello.  Post the code around the select component.  It is almost impossible to help without it.  My immediate guess would be:  Are you binding to the `value` prop?

Comment: @José Ramírez
 Actually, I figured it out I just assigned the current api value to the selected value prop